# SQL Server Managment Studio Failures after Windows Updates

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssms

Greeting; I have a development virtual machine I use daily for my job.  Today I had a Windows Updates KB3212646, KB3197868, KB3185330 install and request reboot.  After rebooting, I started getting errors in applications that ran SQL Statements.  I opened SSMS 2014 to test and was getting different errors on simple selects.  Example, I got all three of these errors from running the simple select a few times in a row.

```
select * from MVXJDTA.MITMAS
--An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Internal connection fatal error. Error state: 18
--An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
--An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I'm running Windows 7 x64 SP1.
I have Visual Studio 2010, 2012, and 2013 installed.
I have SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, and 2016 installed.

I have removed the updates after the failure and I still have the errors. The errors don't occur on SMALL select statements, only larger ones. (MITMAS has 171,252 rows, 224 columns)  Not a massive table by any means, but not a simple one either.  If I do `select top 100 MMCONO, MMITNO from MVXJDTA.MITMAS` I do not seem to get the error.  I have tested in SSMS for 2012, 2014, 2016, and in Visual Studio 2013.

I have not had the problem to till today, I know several Windows Updates installed Tuesday, but I didn't have issues yesterday after that reboot.  I have not installed or uninstalled any other software.

Any assistance is appreciated.

In response to the comment that is can't be happening with the query listed:

[image: Example of Issue in SSMS]

[image: Example of Issue in SSMS]

Comment: Is there anything relevant in the server's management logs?

Comment: the errors won't occur with the query you are running

Comment: I looked in the Event log on the server and the local workstation, but nothing jumps out at me as odd.

Comment: I should say, I wish the errors were not occurring.  Normally, I would agree, it's a simple statement.  I have no triggers on the database, and like I said, it's happening with every server I try.  It appears to be an internal error in Windows or something SQL Server related.  I'm about to try every service pack I can find to install for VS / SQL Server, but I hate to blindly install software without any idea if it'll help.

Comment: It's not just in SSMS.  I have other programs which make calls to SQL Servers getting the same errors randomly.

Comment: My guess would be that your SQL Native Client binary(s) somehow got corrupted.

Comment: I agree @RBarryYoung, I ran repair on all of my SQL and .Net installers listed in Add/Remove Programs to attempt to resolve that to no avail.  I wish I could have tracked down the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I was unable to resolve this issue.  I installed all available service packs for all products, and even reinstalled the three updates listed in the question.  After 10 hours of trouble shooting, and knowing I had to work again today, I started the restore process from backup.  I believe something was corrupted in the .Net framework or Native client, as no software using the SQL Native client could run any statement that returned more than a few rows.

I will snapshot the machine before any more Windows Updates are installed, and advise here if those updates cause the problem to reoccur.

Sorry I couldn't report a better solution.

Billy